# how to detach sidekiq process once started in terminal

Tags: sidekiq

I want to run sidekiq on my production server, I am using this command to start the process

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer,5 -q default -e production
```

How do I detach from the process without stopping it, so that I can close the connection to server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The right answer is lower case **-d**:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -q mailer,5 -q default -e production
```

`sidekiq --help` will list the options:

```
-d, --daemon                     Daemonize process
```

When running -d option, sidekiq will ask for a log file, so the complete command is:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L sidekiq.log -q mailer,5 -q default -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detach it by executing

bundle exec sidekiq **-D** -q mailer,5 -q default -e production

Optionally, you can just use the God gem to run your Sidekiq jobs.

Comment: I already tried this out, it doesn't work, saying invalid option -D, btw i am using capistrano recipe for sidekiq and everything works fine now.

Comment: What recipe? I need help like this